# Adding transition to MaterialPageRoute

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino

I've been trying to use transitions within my RouteGenerator and didn't had any success yet, in my material design I'm just calling the route with the onGenerateRoute using only the "/" string. I would like to use the cupertinoPageRoute transition and tried passing it inside the MaterialPageRoute with the builder inside it.

```
class RouteGenerator {
 static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {

  switch (settings.name) {
    case '/':
      return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Menu()); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```dart
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Menu(),
        );
    }
  }
}
```